# Is there a way to replace only specific occurrences of keywords in a field value without replacing all occurrences?

Tags: sqlite, replace

Given a table 'updates' that contains records comprising two fields, both containing text only:

`existing_value` and `replacement_value`

This table is used to update a 2nd table 'main' with a single field:

`name`

whereby the `name` field is to be updated with a `replacement_value`, replacing all instances of `existing_value` with `replacement_value`. However, what's needed is not a simple update of the 'main' table replacing on the basis of `main.name = updates.repleacement_value` where `main.name = updates.existing_value`.

`main.name`, `updates.existing_value` and `updates.replacement_value` all contain strings that take the form of a simple value such as `Joe` or they can (and mostly do) contain strings that include delimiters to separate multiple values held in a single field e.g. `Joe Soap\\Joe Bloggs\\Joe` (yes I know field stuffing is a terrible idea, but the source data is what it is).

For the purposes of clarification let's assume an example where the following applies:

```
updates.existing_value = 'Joe'
updates.replacement = 'Jose'
```

Main has two records:

```
main.name = 'Joe Soap\\Joe Bloggs\\Joe'
main.name = 'Joe\\Joe Soap\\Joe\\Joe Little'
```

The problem I need to solve is to replace only the standalone `'Joe'` in each record to `'Jose'` without inadvertently affecting 'Joe Soap', 'Joe Bloggs' or 'Joe Little'.

One way to solve the problem is to load each record in 'main' into Python, turn each record into a list, process the list and recompile the string before writing it back to 'main' (a dataframe would be most efficient), but before going this route, I was wondering whether there's a way to achieve the same directly in SQLite?

I've experimented with `LIKE`, `INSTR()` and `REPLACE()`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to curtail `REPLACE()`'s scope in that it'll replace all instances of 'Joe' with 'Jose'.

Is there some other `SQL` method I've not considered or is the problem best tackled outside or `SQLite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delimit the search term:

```
update main
set name =
    trim(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    '\'||name||'\',
                    '\',
                    '\\'
                ),
                '\'||map.old||'\',
                '\'||map.new||'\'
            ),
            '\\',
            '\'
        ),
        '\'
    )
from (
    select distinct
        main.rowid as id,
        updates.existing_value as old,
        updates.replacement as new
    from main inner join updates
    where instr(
        '\'||main.name||'\',
        '\'||updates.existing_value||'\'
    )
) as map
where main.rowid = map.id;
```

1. locate the rows to update
2. prepend and append delimiter so replace can be on `\Joe\`
3. double the delimiters to allow consecutive matches (eg. `Joe\Joe\Joe`)
4. do the replacement for each `existing_value`
5. undo the delimiter doubling from (3)
6. trim the extra delimiters added in (2)

**Note:**
If multiple updates apply to the same row, the result is [nondeterministic](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from).

Comment: Thanks.  I works, but because it's nondeterministic I'll have to dedupe the strings beforehand or some changes won't be processed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to the answer, could be to split the data and store it in another table that can:-

1. Easily have such changes applied,
2. re-generate the original source (changes applied if made), and
3. perhaps simplify matters in the future (perhaps even replace the awkardness of the original table).

Splitting strings requires recursion, fortunately SQLite allows recursion via **C**ommon **T**able **E**xpressions (temporary tables that exist just for the duration of the statement being executed).

How recursion is made is described here [**SQLite - The With Clause**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursive_common_table_expressions).

Here's an example/demo of undertaking the above, with example data (yours plus some more) and results down to a solution that rather than updating the original table (easy enough to do) generates the data after the table that holds the split data has been updating to change just occurrences of exactly **Joe** not **Joe Blah** nor **Joey**, it also handles multiple occurrences of exactly **Joe** should that also exist (you could even update just the first or just the last or others without too much hassle)

- This is because not only is individual name (Joe, Joe Blah) extracted/split but also other information about the source row is stored along with the individual name such as

  1. the pos of the name with the list of the names
  2. the full name from the updates table
  3. the rowid (would require a ROWID table (i.e. one that is not a virtual table or defined using the WITHOUT ROWID clause))

Here's the SQL (with comments to explain):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS updates;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS updates (name TEXT);
INSERT INTO updates VALUES 
    /* Original Values From the Question */
    ('Joe Soap\\Joe Bloggs\\Joe'),
    ('Joe\\Joe Soap\\Joe\\Joe Little'),
    /* Some potentiall more taxing data */
    ('Jane\\Jane Doe\\Fred Bloggs\\Bert\\Bert Bert\\Fred'),
    ('Joey Joey\\Joey\\Jo\\Joe\\Joey Smith\\Joe')
;

/* Prepare the table to hold the split data */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS updates_split;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS updates_split (id INTEGER, name_from_split TEXT, base TEXT, pos INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (base,name_from_split,pos));

/* explanatory/testing version of the splitter (i.e. outputs resultant data rathe than actually INSERTing it into the table) */
/* Bar the end use of the CTE (the last line) it is idenntical to the actual CTE */
WITH
    cte_sep AS (SELECT('\\')), /* First CTE that allows the seperator to just be coded once */
    /* The recursice CTE that splits the names according to the seperator */
    cte_split(rowid,current,rest,base_just_in_case,pos) AS 
        (
            SELECT
                rowid,
                /* note that the seperator is added to the end to allow the final split */
                substr(name||(SELECT * FROM cte_sep),1,instr(name,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep))-1), /* extract the current name */
                substr(name||(SELECT * FROM cte_sep),instr(name,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep))+length((SELECT * FROM cte_sep))), /* the rest of the test */
                name,
                1 /* first position i.e. 1 for each input/source row */ 
            FROM updates
            /* the UNION that causes the recursion */
            UNION ALL SELECT 
                rowid,
                substr(rest,1,instr(rest,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep))-1),
                substr(rest,instr(rest,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep)) + length((SELECT * FROM cte_sep))),
                base_just_in_case,
                pos + 1 /* the subsequent position value 2 then 3 then 4 .... */
            FROM cte_split
            /* End the recursion !!!!IMPORTANT!!! else endless loop i.e. when no more data */
            WHERE length(rest) > 0
            LIMIT 100 /* JUST IN CASE (shouldn't be needed) end the recursion 100 might be too small but OK for the demo */
        )
SELECT * FROM cte_split; /* output the data */
/* EXACTLY the same as the previous BUT INSERTs into the secondary updates_split table */
WITH
    cte_sep AS (SELECT('\\')),
    cte_split(rowid,current,rest,base_just_in_case,pos) AS 
        (
            SELECT
                rowid,
                substr(name||(SELECT * FROM cte_sep),1,instr(name,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep))-1),
                substr(name||(SELECT * FROM cte_sep),instr(name,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep))+length((SELECT * FROM cte_sep))),
                name,
                1
            FROM updates
            UNION ALL SELECT 
                rowid,
                substr(rest,1,instr(rest,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep))-1),
                substr(rest,instr(rest,(SELECT * FROM cte_sep)) + length((SELECT * FROM cte_sep))),
                base_just_in_case,
                pos + 1
            FROM cte_split
            WHERE length(rest) > 0
            LIMIT 100
        )
INSERT INTO updates_split SELECT rowid,current,base_just_in_case,pos FROM cte_split;

/* Show resultant updates_split table */
SELECT * FROM updates_split; /* should reflect the same as the first CTE */
/* Example of generating the original data */
SELECT group_concat(name_from_split,'//') AS name FROM updates_split GROUP BY base ORDER BY id,base,pos;
/* Update as per question */
UPDATE updates_split SET name_from_split = 'Jose' WHERE name_from_split = 'Joe';
/* Generate from the updated updates_split table */
SELECT group_concat(name_from_split,'//') AS name FROM updates_split GROUP BY base ORDER BY id,base,pos;
/* Cleanup the test/demo/example environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS updates;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS updates_split;
```

**Results**

**First**,The output from the first WITH .... that SELECTs i.e. the proposed data to populate the updates_split table:-

[image]

- i.e. as can be seen

  - the rowid is as per the original data, for a ROWID table this can be used to uniquely identify the source row
  - the names are progressively being extracted as the **current** name
  - the rest of the data is ready/extracted for the next recursion
  - the original source data is extracted (could potential identify the source row)
  - the position of the extracted name within the list (allows the original data to be re-created)

**Second** the output via a straightforward select from the updates_split table after it has been populated via the 2nd WITH .... (exactly the same as the first output (at least it should be) except that the now useless **rest** column has been dropped):-

[image]

**Third** the output from the generation of the original data from the updates_split table:-

[image]

**Last** the output (generation) BUT after the update that changes exactly **Joe** to **Jose**:-

[image]

- the last row showing that Joey/Jo have not been changed BUT that both occurrences of Joe have been changed. aka the more taxing data has been handled.

Of course the updates_split table could be used to update the original updates table quite easily.

Here's an [SQLFiddle of the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/18304)